# this code will not run on Qtspim

Tags: assembly, mips, heapsort

this a mips code for a heapsort. When i try to run it, i get the following error messages
syntax error on line 149 (array: .word 54,23,56,32,99,7,4,2,88,9,11,21,39,55,100,101,43,1,3,69,-5,-24,-17,0)
and another instruction reference undefined symbol on line 14. 
I have already look at it many times and i still don't see any mistakes. Please let me know if you find any.
this is the code:

```
.text
.globl main
main:

  la $a0, array # a0 = &array

  la $t0, size
  lw $a1, 0($t0) # a1 = size(array)

  jal heapsort

  # print the array
  move $t0, $a0
  add $t1, $zero, $zero
printloop:
  li $v0, 1
  lw $a0, 0($t0)
  addi $t0, $t0, 4
  addi $t1, $t1, 1
  syscall
  li $v0, 4
  la $a0, space 
  syscall

  bne $t1, $a1, printloop   # while( t1 != size )
  li $v0, 4
  la $a0, newline
  syscall

done:
  jr $ra

heapsort: # a0 = &array, a1 = size(array)
  addi $sp, $sp, -8
  sw $a1, 0($sp)  # save size
  sw $a2, 4($sp)  # save a2
  sw $ra, 8($sp)  # save return address


  move $a2, $a1  # n will be stored in a2
  addi $a2, $a2, -1    # n = size - 1
  ble $a2,$zero, end_heapsort  # if (n <= 0 ) return;

  jal make_heap  # a0 = arr, a1 = size

  add $a1, $zero, $zero # clear $a1
heapsort_loop:
  # swap(array[0],array[n])
  lw $t0, 0($a0)
  sll $t1, $a2, 2  #t1 = bytes(n)
  add $t1, $t1, $a0
  lw $t2, 0($t1)
  sw $t0, 0($t1)
  sw $t2, 0($a0)

  addi $a2, $a2, -1 # n--
  jal bubble_down  # a0 = &array, a1 = 0, a2 = n

  bnez $a2, heapsort_loop
end_heapsort:
  lw $ra, 8($sp)
  lw $a2, 4($sp)
  lw $a1, 0($sp)
  addi $sp, $sp, 8
  jr $ra

make_heap: # a0 = &array, a1 = size
  addi $sp, $sp, -12
  sw $a1, 0($sp)
  sw $a2, 4($sp)
  sw $ra, 8($sp)

  addi $a2, $a1, -1  # a2 = size - 1

  addi $a1, $a1, -1  # start_index = size - 1
  srl $a1, $a1, 1  # start_index /= 2

  blt $a1, $zero, end_make_heap  # if(start_index < 0) return

make_heap_loop:
  jal bubble_down # a0 = &array, a1 = start_index, a2 = size-1
  addi $a1, $a1, -1
  ble $zero, $a1, make_heap_loop

end_make_heap:
  lw $ra, 8($sp)
  lw $a2, 4($sp)
  lw $a1, 0($sp)
  addi $sp, $sp, 12
  jr $ra

#bubble_down is a leaf in the call graph
bubble_down: # a0 = &array, a1 = s_idx, a2 = end
  move $t0, $a1  # index = s_idx
  sll $t1, $t0, 2  # child = index*2+1
  addi $t1, $t1, 1

  bgt $t1, $a2, end_bubble_down

bubble_down_loop:

  #if ( child < end && arr[child] < arr[child+1] )
  ble $a2, $t1, skipinc
  sll $t3, $t1, 2  # get bytes(child)
  add $t3, $t3, $a0
  lw $t3, 0($t3)  # t3 = arr[child]
  sll $t4, $t1, 2 #get bytes(child)
  addi $t4, $t4, 4 #t4 = bytes(child+1)
  add $t4, $t4, $a0
  lw $t4, 0($t4)  #t4 = arr[child+1]
  ble $t4, $t3, skipinc

  addi $t1, $t1, 1  # child++

skipinc:
  sll $t3, $t0, 2  # get bytes(index)
  add $t3, $t3, $a0
  lw $t4, 0($t3)  #t4 = arr[index], t3 = &arr[index]

  sll $t5, $t1, 2  # get bytes(child)
  add $t5, $t5, $a0
  lw $t6, 0($t5)  #t6 = arr[child], t5 = &arr[child]

  ble $t6, $t4, end_bubble_down

  # swap(arr[index],arr[child]
  # note: t4 = arr[index], t6 = arr[child], t3 = &arr[index], t5 = &arr[child]
  sw $t4, 0($t5)
  sw $t6, 0($t3)

  move $t0, $t1  # index = child

  sll $t1, $t0, 1  # child = index*2+1
  addi $t1, $t1, 1
  ble $t1, $a2, bubble_down_loop

end_bubble_down:
  jr $ra

.data
# the array that holds unordered data
array: .word 54,23,56,32,99,7,4,2,88,9,11,21,39,55,100,101,43,1,3,69,-5,-24,-17,0
size: .word 24
space: .asciiz " "
newline: .asciiz "\n"
```

Comment: Maybe it doesn't know about `$zero`, try using `$0` instead. As for the other error, if it is really on that line (what you pasted is only 146 lines) `array` could be a reserved word, try using something else.

Comment: Thanks I ll make  those changes. Hope it runs.

Comment: Ohhh still have the same message. It seems nothing changed. Any ideas  please???

Comment: Verify this is actually the code you have and where the errors are. As I said, there isn't even a line 149.

Comment: The syntax error points below word on the line in .data , array:  .word 54, 23, 56 , 32...)

Comment: Can't see anything wrong there, but make sure your `-` signs are proper ascii and not the unicode sillyness. Also maybe you hit a line length limit, try breaking it up.

Comment: You write first ~200 lines, and then figure out you have syntax error? How did you manage that, I'm curious... Try to write in iterative way, and compile the thing between to catch up syntax errors early. Also often short parts of code can be run already in debugger to verify their correctness (although if run as whole it wouldn't do anything meaningful).

Answer (score 2):

The syntax error can be fixed by putting a space after each "," in the array .word:
so "54, 23, 56, 32, 99, 7, 4, 2, ..."

Comment: Thanks. Did not see that. Will definitely do that and I hope the code runs this time around. :)

Comment: hi there.I made the changes and i am pretty sure it was the right change. (thanks for that) but i still get this error message when i attempt to run the code " instruction reference undefined symbol at 0x0040002c [0x0040002c] 0x3c010000 lui $1, 0[size]       ; 14: la $t0, size. can you tell me what that means. i have looked over and over again but i don't see where the problem is. thanks

Comment: or any other person.

Comment: Make sure you have size: .word 24 in your .data section.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate it

Comment: Checked that but I still can't get this code to run. Any thing else please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to reproduce the error you describe with QtSpim 9.1.12 for Windows. So you're either using a different version of QtSpim that behaves differently, and/or not running the exact code you've shown us, and/or didn't reinitialize the simulator before reloading the assembly code.

You *do* however have a bug in your code. Well, maybe more than one, but at least one that was obvious:

At `done:` you try to end your program with `jr $ra`. However, you've altered the value of `$ra` at `jal heapsort` without preserving it. So what happens at that last `jr $ra` is that you'll jump back to the printing code, which then will execute again. And the first thing you do there is `$t0 = $a0`, where `$a0` is supposed to contain the address of `array`. But `$a0` no longer contains the address of the array, because right before `jr $ra` you did `la $a0, newline`.

TL;DR: Whenever you do a `jal` you're modifying `$ra`. If you need the previous value of `$ra` at some later point you need to preserve it (in another register, in a memory variable, or on the stack).